# iOS map location with x.y

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, mapkit, core-location, latitude-longitude

I have an array of x,y points of location. I don't know how to use it because it's not long/lat.

for example: X=217338 , Y=703099

I want to know how to use it on the iphone SDK and with which framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What format are they in, if they aren't long/lat?

Comment: You have tagged the framework: it's the MapKit

Comment: Where do the x,y points come from? from the iphone device or from an external source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what is represented by those values, there isn't really anything you can do with them. Assuming you can convert them to Latitude/Longitude values, this is how you'd be able to center your map at that (X, Y) coordinate:

```
//Import the <MapKit/MapKit.h> and <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> framework 
//and then this will go in your implementation file:
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(xConvertedToLat, yConvertedToLong);
//Set the region your map will display centered on the above coord and spanning 250m on x-axis and 250 on y-axis
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, 250, 250);
//You should have a MKMapView object
[myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

You can iterate through this for each object in your array, but you won't see anything appear until the last (x, y) coordinate is set.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know in which format your values are.
If they are not lon/lat they can be anything like meters or inches or half arm lengths or even normalized doughnut holes.

In any case you need to come up with an conversion method because `MKMapKit` only understands geo coordinates (long/lat).

If you have clarified that you should take a look at the [location awarness guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1) from apple. There are also some other good sources for mapkit stuff like [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial).